# Testing Ansible roles in Drone CI, systemd services not working

Tags: docker, ansible, drone.io

When testing Ansible roles, my systemd services fail to startup. This is the error I get,

```
TASK [memcached : Packages Present] ********************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=[u'memcached', u'libmemcached'])

TASK [memcached : Service Enabled] *********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find the requested service memcached: host"}
```

My .drone.yml

---

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: samdoran/centos7-ansible
    privileged: true
    commands:
      - echo 'sslverify=0' >> /etc/yum.conf
      - yum install -y redhat-lsb-core python-devel openldap-devel git gcc gcc-c++ python2-pip
      - pip install -U pip tox
      - tox
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.8

    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/
      - /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=true
      - DRONE_HOST=https://example.server
      - DRONE_ADMIN=drone
      - DRONE_VOLUME=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      - DRONE_GOGS_GIT_USERNAME=drone
      - DRONE_GOGS_GIT_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX
      - DRONE_GOGS=true
      - DRONE_GOGS_URL=https://example.gogs
      - DRONE_SECRET=${DRONE_SECRET}

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:0.8

    command: agent
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000
      - DRONE_SECRET=${DRONE_SECRET}
      - DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.24
```

I've tried to do a memcached install manually, starting a base centos:7 docker container from my fedora workstation, and the service starts as expected when --privileged. The drone dockers are running on a RHEL 7 host.  I have already set the repository to trusted, within the Drone interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is related to how the entrycommands are implemented, if you override the commands it doesn't init like expected.  Thus the workaround is to start the container, detach, then send commands to the running container.

```
---

pipeline:
  system:
    image: cyberpunkspike/docker-centos7-ansible:latest
    labels:
      com.amtrustna.it.infr.serv.system: "true"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    init: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
    detach: true

  exec:
    image: docker
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    commands:
      - CONTAINER_ID="$(docker ps -qf "label=com.amtrustna.it.infr.serv.system")"
      - test -n "$CONTAINER_ID" || { echo "Container Not Found"; exit 1 ;}
      - docker exec -t "$CONTAINER_ID" sh -c "export TERM=xterm-256color; cd $PWD && tox"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add readonly rights to `/sys/fs/cgroup` to your `volumes`section:

    `- /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro`

The full explanation [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/).

Comment: Yea, but where?

I already tried doing that in the `.drone.yml`

Comment: Placed it in all three locations, useless.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can drop the whole priviledged/systemd stuff by replacing the init-command with [systemctl.py](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement). It may even give you different error diagnostics.